# How do I add extra time to a timer in android

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

I dont know how I add extra time to a timer that is running.
Evertime I press a button I want to add 1 second.
So my question is, how do I do this?

Here is my timer(code):

```
    private void TimerGame(){
     new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {

         TextView mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTv);
         Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startGameBtn);
         TextView go = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvGo);

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             mTextField.setText("" +millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             mTextField.setText("15");
             start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             go.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

             reset();
         }
      }.start();
    }
```

Comment: In that case I would advise you to make a custom implementation and not using the CountDownTimer, have you considered such approach?

Comment: Besides the custom implementation I added, you can just copy the CountdownTimer you are using and creating a method to extend the time to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I looked into `CountDownTimer` there is no method to what you want.

However, I made a small example of what you can do. I haven't tested it but it shouldn't be too hard to put it on track.

```
    private Handler countdownHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable updateCountdownTask = new UpdateCountdownTaskRunnable();

    private int timeSeconds;

    private class UpdateCountdownTaskRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timeSeconds -= 1;
            if (timeSeconds == 0) {
                stopWhatever();
            } else {
                updateWhatever();
                countdownHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }
    }

    private void start() {
        timeSeconds = 20;//seconds
        countdownHandler.postDelayed(updateCountdownTask, 0);
    }

    private void stop(){};
    private void update(){};
    private void addTime(int time){ timeSeconds += time; };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! its working but when its on 0, it just continues. I am putting this timeSeconds in a label. and updating the time doesnt go so smooth.

Comment: yes it did kind of, I am trying to display the time to as it get 1 extra second, now it only freezes. So I am still busy with this haha. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: oh.. I didnt see the last private void, i will try it and let you know!